# Replace every even x2 occurrence of a substring in a string

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas, string

I've got a dataframe similar to the below:

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1' : ['apple'],
     'col2': ['orange'],
     'col3': ['444472.01 200028.82 444202.48 199906.88 444122.83 199853.13 '\
              '444038.36 199766.42 443859.82 199486.80 443783.89 199386.59 '\
              '443750.45 199352.83 443658.39 199278.62 443516.05 199182.52 '\
              '443339.32 199080.79 442754.88 198770.39 442518.70 198672.85 '\
              '442339.97 198624.31 442150.72 198594.03 441999.44 198586.21']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

The string in col3 is multiple single coordinates separated by a space.
I'm trying to convert that string into couples of coordinates, i.e. every two coordinates to be separated with a comma ','.

i.e.: current string:

```
'444472.01 200028.82 444202.48 199906.88 444122.83 199853.13 444038.36 199766.42 443859.82 
199486.80 443783.89 199386.59 443750.45 199352.83 443658.39 199278.62 443516.05 199182.52 
443339.32 199080.79 442754.88 198770.39 442518.70 198672.85 442339.97 198624.31 442150.72 
198594.03 441999.44 198586.21'
```

output string:

```
'444472.01 200028.82, 444202.48 199906.88, 444122.83 199853.13, 444038.36 199766.42, 443859.82 
199486.80, 443783.89 199386.59, 443750.45 199352.83, 443658.39 199278.62, 443516.05 199182.52, 
443339.32 199080.79, 442754.88 198770.39, 442518.70 198672.85, 442339.97 198624.31, 442150.72 
198594.03, 441999.44 198586.21'
```

I found the function below that replaces a substring with another substring (in this case ' ', with ',') but at a very specific location, **My Question:** How can I make it repeat to replace every even occurrence to achieve the output above, **OR** if you have a better idea to do this then please do share!

```py
def nth_repl_all(s, sub, repl, nth):
    find = s.find(sub)
    # loop util we find no match
    i = 1
    while find != -1:
        # if i  is equal to nth we found nth matches so replace
        if i == nth:
            s = s[:find]+repl+s[find + len(sub):]
            i = 0
        # find + len(sub) + 1 means we start after the last match
        find = s.find(sub, find + len(sub) + 1)
        i += 1
    return s
```

Thanks Very much!

Comment: Note that when posing a question like this you should try and provide a minimal example. By providing the containing dict `d` with a bunch of extra data that is not involved in your core question, or the panda dataframe context, you are likely to occlude what you actually are trying to ask. You can provide a much simplified list with the same properties and be more sure answers are appropriate.

Comment: @NathanielFord Agreed, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.Series.str.replace`:

```
print (df["col3"].str.replace("(\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+)\s", "\\1, "))

0    444472.01 200028.82, 444202.48 199906.88, 4441...
Name: col3, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my first time answer but:

For what you wanted I would recommend:

```
d['col3'] = d['col3'][0].split()
lst = ""

#enumerate list e.g. for loop (but with index)
for i,k in enumerate(d['col3']):
    #pass even coordinates
    if i % 2:
        pass
    else:
        #add string together with spaces & commas
        lst+= k + " " + d['col3'][i+1]+","+" "

#finish list into col3
d['col3'] = lst[:-2]
```

Output:

```
'444472.01 200028.82, 444202.48 199906.88, 444122.83 199853.13, 444038.36 199766.42, 443859.82 199486.80, 443783.89 199386.59, 443750.45 199352.83, 443658.39 199278.62, 443516.05 199182.52, 443339.32 199080.79, 442754.88 198770.39, 442518.70 198672.85, 442339.97 198624.31, 442150.72 198594.03, 441999.44 198586.21'
```

But Personally if I was working coordinates I would keep them all in a tuple which is very easy to access

```
#split the list into col3
d['col3'] = d['col3'][0].split()
lst = []
#enumerate list e.g. for loop (but with index)
for i,k in enumerate(d['col3']):
    #pass even coordinates
    if i % 2:
        pass
    else:
        #append float equivlant to new list
        lst.append((float(k),float(d['col3'][i+1])))

#finish list into col3
d['col3'] = lst
```

Output:

```
[(444472.01, 200028.82), (444202.48, 199906.88), (444122.83, 199853.13), (444038.36, 199766.42), (443859.82, 199486.8), (443783.89, 199386.59), (443750.45, 199352.83), (443658.39, 199278.62), (443516.05, 199182.52), (443339.32, 199080.79), (442754.88, 198770.39), (442518.7, 198672.85), (442339.97, 198624.31), (442150.72, 198594.03), (441999.44, 198586.21)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` does the job

```py
import re
string = '444472.01 200028.82 444202.48 199906.88 444122.83 199853.13 444038.36 199766.42'
re.findall('\d+\.\d+\s\d+\.\d+',string)
```

outputs

```
['444472.01 200028.82', '444202.48 199906.88', '444122.83 199853.13', '444038.36 199766.42']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using .apply()...

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1' : ['apple'],
     'col2': ['orange'],
     'col3': ['444472.01 200028.82 444202.48 199906.88 444122.83 199853.13 '\
              '444038.36 199766.42 443859.82 199486.80 443783.89 199386.59 '\
              '443750.45 199352.83 443658.39 199278.62 443516.05 199182.52 '\
                  '443339.32 199080.79 442754.88 198770.39 442518.70 198672.85 '\
                      '442339.97 198624.31 442150.72 198594.03 441999.44 198586.21']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

def l2t(x):
    n = 2
    sep = ' '
    n_split_groups = []

    groups = x.split(sep)
    while len(groups):
        n_split_groups.append(sep.join(groups[:n]))
        groups = groups[n:]

    tups = []

    for group in n_split_groups:
        tups.append(tuple(group.split(' ')))
        
    return tups
    
df['col4'] = df['col3'].apply(l2t)
print(df)

'''Shows:
    col1    col2                                               col3  \
0  apple  orange  444472.01 200028.82 444202.48 199906.88 444122...   

                                                col4  
0  [(444472.01, 200028.82), (444202.48, 199906.88...  

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an example that uses iterators over regex, this is what you can do:

```
ls = ['1 2 3 4 5 6']  # Simple form of your input
lx = ls[0].split(' ')  # Break it out into a real list based on space delimiters.
# range(len(lx) // 2) gives us a range of ints between 0 and half the length of our list.
# Then we use this to grab pairs of elements (each n and n+1 element)
# We also join each pair with a space so they are a single space delimited element.
pairs = [" ".join([lx[(i*2)], lx[(i*2)+1]]) for i in range(len(lx) // 2)] 

# Finally, join all our elements into a single comma-delimited list of pairs.
output = ", ".join(pairs)
```

Copy-paste into a repl and you get this, which matches your expected output:

```
>>> [output]
'1 2, 3 4, 5 6'
```

There are more efficient ways to do this, but this approach can be more clear than regex in some cases. You can omit the join on commas to leave things in a paired element format. You can also make the pairs a tuple instead of a list if that is preferable for your use case.